# Mobile website hide address bar safari browser with anchor inks

Tags: mobile-safari, scrollto, address-bar

Below is the function for hiding the address bar on a mobile for Safari, but how would build some additional logic that this function ONLY is initiated when there is no # in the URl present. Because when there is a # it needs to move to the anchor link.

So, when i have http://www.mymobilesite.com/index.html#start below function don't need to run.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  // Set a timeout...
  setTimeout(function(){
  // Hide the address bar!
  window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
  });
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance!
Marcellino

Answer (score 0):

Test for presence of hash:

```
if(!window.location.hash)
```

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/